# Missed dhuhr prayer because of migraine?

Tags: salat, sick

Today I missed dhuhr prayer because I had a very bad migraine that I couldn't get out of bed to do wudu or pray (I was also nauseous). I slept through dhuhr prayer and woke up an hour before maghrib prayer (before breaking fast, yes I was fasting) and prayed only asr prayer. Have I sinned by not praying dhuhr prayer even though I had a very bad migraine?

Comment: You can pray 4 units immediately, Allah knows your problem.

Comment: Even though I am very late to this I would like to mention that even when you are suffering from paralysis unless you don't know, salah is still wajib on you.

The people with paralysis pray it in their minds, or If their eyes aren't paralyzed they pray with those, or if their ears aren't they pray with their minds again, just in a specific manner of praising Allah and it counts as a salah of the specific time the action is done at.

Though each sin except blasphemy is forgivable so ask Allah for forgiveness sincerely and he will forgive you.

Answer (score 0):

No you have not sinned at all 
We are told the body has power over us
if our body is unwell or weak we do not do namaz until we feel well enough to do so 
for example if you wake up for fajr and you feel dizzy you're told to sit down and wait for the dizziness to leave then complete your fujer namaz 
Look after your body 
But soon as your well do prays 
always remember that Allah knows everything you think feel and go through  Allah knows your intentions ❤️ trust Allah knows u were not well 
Allah loves you 500× more then your own mother